# Having trouble with JQuery returning something to it original position after mouseout

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate, slide

I'm new here. I'm working with some basic JQuery but am having an issue.  Did you ever see one of those boxes on a site where you hover over it and an arrow shape in the box moves a few pixels to the left and when you move the mouse out, it goes back?  Well anyway, with the code iv come up with, the mouse over effect works ok but the mouse-out is not returning the arrow to the original position. actually, the more you hover, the more left the arrow does.

I bet many of you have see the effect im going for but I have a feeling I'm not setting it up the best way. Can anybody help? Iv made it this far on my own. Just a little bit stuck.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>-</title>
<style type="text/css">

#red {
    height: 80px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #df0000;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 998;
    display: none;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
#gray {
    height: 80px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #232323;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 997;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
#wording{
    height: 80px;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    background-image: url(getit.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#wrap {
    height: 80px;
    width: 200px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -40px;
    margin-left: -100px;
}

#arrow {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #df0000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 15px;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

$('#wording').mouseenter(function(){
  $('#red').animate({'width': 'toggle'});
    $('#arrow').css('color','white');
     $('#arrow').delay(100).animate({'left': '-=3px'}, "fast"); 
});


$('#wording').mouseleave(function(){
  $('#red').animate({'width': 'toggle'});
    $('#arrow').css('color','red');
      $('#arrow').delay(100).animate({'right': '+=3px'}, 'fast');
});


});

</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="wrap">

<div id="wording">
<div id="arrow">></div>
</div>
<div id="red"></div>
<div id="gray"></div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

not:

```
$('#arrow').delay(100).animate({'left': '-=3px'}, 'fast');
```

but:

```
$('#arrow').delay(100).animate({'right': '-=3px'}, 'fast');
```

your script can also be like :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $red   = $('#red');
    var $arrow = $('#arrow');
    $('#wording').hover(
      function() {
        $red.animate({'width': 'toggle'});
        $arrow.css('color', 'white').delay(100).animate({'right': '-=3px'}, "fast");
      }, function() {
        $red.animate({'width': 'toggle'});
        $arrow.css('color', 'red').delay(100).animate({'right': '+=3px'}, 'fast');
     });
});​
```

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/jqrET/1/

Comment: Thank you soo much! I'm still learning. This helped me understand better thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking it because you move left -3 and move right +3. You can try to move right -3. See if it works.

Comment: Guys, I actually spoke too soon.  What I was trying to do is on hover it was suppose to slide the red background in (which works fine) but as far as the arrow. on mouse over, it was suppose to go to the left 3px then back tot he right 3 px.  the mouse out wasn't suppose to have any effect on the arrow, just remove the red background again.   does this make sense hopefully?  hover would bring out the red and move the arrow left 3 then back to original.

Comment: here is the code I have so far. Cant find my bug ( its just the hover effect. I didn't do the rollout yet. The hover is still messed up. $(document).ready(function() {
    var $red   = $('#red');
    var $arrow = $('#arrow');
    $('#wording').mouseover(
      function() {
        
        $arrow.css('color', 'white').delay(180).animate({'right': '+=3px'}, fast) (function() {
  $arrow.css.delay(300).animate({'right': '-=3px'}, 'fast')
  });
  
  
 });
 });